# Obter lista de aplicativos instalados no computador

Tags: c#

Gostaria de obter uma lista com todos os programas que estão instalados no computador e exibir em um DataGridView com (C# Windows Forms Application).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system

Comment: Olá. Você obterá mais respostas, e mais rápido, se for mais claro. O que você precisa exatamente? Aqui no SOpt, quanto mais precisa for sua pergunta, mais resultados você obtêm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode obter a lista de programas instalados lendo as entradas do registro **SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall** do windows, da seguinte forma:

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
{
    foreach(string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
        }
    }
}
```

*Adaptado da resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/908907/1639385 do StackOverflow em inglês.*